# Trying to set off a alarm if I get a SMS message!! Cant build the following code :(

Tags: android, sms

```
package com.smith.johnathan.phonefinder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;



import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PhoneFinder extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;
    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(PhoneFinder.ACTION)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                    SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                    sb.append("Received SMS Message\nFrom: ");
                    sb.append(messages.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                    sb.append("\n----Message----\n");
                    sb.append(messages.getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
            }
            Log.i(PhoneFinder.LOG_TAG, "[SMSApp] onReceiveIntent: " + sb);
            Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void beep()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneFinder.class, AlarmService.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    };
}
```

Comment: First of all, please provide more information such as what error messages you are getting.  Second, make sure to go back and accept answers to questions you posted.  If you don't accept answers, then people won't want to give you answers.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly in onReceive() have you called this beep function?

Answer (score 0):

The `beep()` method that you have created is never getting called (so it seems to have no need), however if for some reason you do need it you will need to pass it a parameter to make your Activity start work properly.  I would recommend pulling those lines of code into `onReceive()`, giving you the following:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PhoneFinder.ACTION)) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                sb.append("Received SMS Message\nFrom: ");
                sb.append(messages.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                sb.append("\n----Message----\n");
                sb.append(messages.getDisplayMessageBody());
            }
        }
        Log.i(PhoneFinder.LOG_TAG, "[SMSApp] onReceiveIntent: " + sb);
        Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
    }
}
```

I renamed your Intent so it doesn't have the same name as the parameter being passed in.  You also must make sure that every Activity you use in your application is defined in the AndroidManifest; your application will crash when you try to start a new Activity you didn't define with an `<activity>` tag.

If you have further errors at build or runtime, please post the output explicitly.

I highly recommend reading [this SDK document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) as well.

Cheers.